# Resizing a QDialog after adding components to a child widget

Tags: qt, size, qwidget

I'm a bit new to QT but have to work on existing code. Here's the case:
I have a class extending QDialog. the constructor sets a QGridLayout then adding three other widgets to it. One of the widgets is a QScrollArea containing a QGroupBox. this QGroupBox has a QVBoxLayout and there I'm adding a list of widgets at runtime. The size of the scroll area should grow until a given limit is reached before showing the scrollbars so that they are only used when the dialog would grow too high. I've found that the sizeHint of the outer layout doesn't update when the sizeHint of the scroll area updates. How can I refresh this, or is there a better way to resize the parent dialog?

Answer (score 0):

What about using widgetResizable property of QScrollArea? It should try to resize view to avoid using scorllbars.